# ngfor to display in multiple table rows

Tags: python, html, angular, html-table

I have a python list to be displayed using Angular. Entire list of more than 200 objects are getting displayed in single table row. How can I make it to display in multiple rows?

```
List=[1,2,3,4,5, .......100}
```

My HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of List">
     <td>
       {{item}}
     </td>
   </ng-container>
</tr>
</table>
```

Current output:

```
1,2,3,4,5, ........100
```

Need:

```
1,2,3,4,......20
21,22,........40
41............60
61............80
81...........100
```

I need the td data to wrap to next row and not overflow in the same row.

Comment: @VasudeDeshpande try edited solution. It will serve your purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it something like this.

In your component create one instance variable array of no of rows. Suppose you want 20 elements per row

```
rows:number[]=[];
```

In `constructor` or in `ngOnInit` initialize it as

```
this.rows= Array.from(Array(Math.ceil(List.length/20)).keys());
```

Now in your templet use it as

```
<table>
   <tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
        <td *ngFor="let item of items|slice:row*20:row*20+20"> {{item}} </td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

Slice is a angular provided pipe.

Comment: That will create 100 rows

Comment: @VasudevDeshpande try edited solution. It will serve your purpose

Comment: Let me try it. Thanks for the step by step info. I am new to angular.

Answer (score 1):

You could place `*ngFor` directive directly over `tr` to repeat `List` collection data in each row.

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of List">
     <td>
       {{item}}
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: In that case I will end up with 100 rows

Comment: @VasudevDeshpande could you please rephrase your question then.. It quite confusing.. what exactly you're expecting?

Comment: @VasudevDeshpande you need to repeat 20 sequence in each row??

Answer (score 1):

If you know the List consists of 100 items always, then why not break them into 5 smaller arrays of 20 items each and then make List=[[1,2...20], [21...40], [41...60]...]? If thats not an option, then you can write your own custom pipe in Angular that does exactly the same thing and do

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of List | yourpipe">
```